# Biquadratic extension of global function fields with cyclic decomposition groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology, function-fields

Let $F$ be a global function field, for example $F={\mathbb F}_q(t)$, the field of rational functions in one variable over a finite field ${\mathbb F}_q\,$.

> **Question.** What would be an example of a global function field $F$ and a finite Galois extension $E/F$ with non-cyclic Galois group $G=\{1,a,b,ab\}$ of order 4 such that all decomposition groups for $E/F$ are *cyclic*?

**Motivation.** Let $E/F$ be as above. Consider the following three-dimensional $F$-tori:
\begin{align*}
 &T_1=R^1_{E/F} {\Bbb G}_m:=\ker\big[R_{E/F} {\Bbb G}_m \to {\Bbb G}_{m,F}\big],\\
 &T_2=(R_{E/F} {\Bbb G}_m)/{\Bbb G}_{m,F}\,.
\end{align*}
Then
$$Ш^1(F,T_1)\cong{\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z},\quad\ Ш^2(F,T_2)\cong {\Bbb Z}/2{\Bbb Z}.$$
See Sansuc, J.-J., Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres.
J. Reine Angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12–80, Example 5.6 and Remark 1.9.4.

Sansuc considers  *number fields* $F={\Bbb Q}$ ,  $E={\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{13},\sqrt{17})$.
I am looking for a similar example with function fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$E= \mathbb F_q ( \sqrt{t}, \sqrt{t^2-1} ) $ over $F =\mathbb F_q(t)$ does the trick if $q$ is congruent to $1$ mod $4$. It suffices to check that at each place where one of the extensions ramifies, the other is split, as this clearly gives a cyclic decomposition group, and unramified places are always cyclic.

The first extension ramifies at $0, \infty$. At $t=0$, the second extension $y^2=t^2-1 $ locally looks like $y^2 = 0-1 = -1$ which is split since $q \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. We can write  the second extension as $\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)^2= 1- \frac{1}{t^2}$, which at $t=\infty$ locally looks like $\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)^2 = 1- \frac{1}{\infty^2} = 1- 0 =1$, which is split.

The second extension ramifies at $1,-1$ where the first extension locally looks respectively like $y^2=1$ and $y^2=-1$, which again are split since $q\equiv 1\bmod 4$.

Comment: Many thanks for the promt and very helpful answer!

Answer (score 4):

For a different type of answer: over any field $K$, take two double coverings $C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, $D\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ with disjoint branch loci; let $\sigma  $ and $\tau $ be the corresponding involutions of $C$ and $D$.  Now let $E:=C\times _{\mathbb{P}^1}D$. Then $\pi :E\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ is a branched covering
with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$. The involution $(\sigma ,\tau )$ of $E$ is fixed point free; this implies that all  ramification points of $\pi $ have multiplicity 2, hence decomposition group $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: If $K$ has a nontrivial quadratic extension then I don't think this works, as the Galois group of the residue field is included in the decomposition group which can make it larger than $\mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: @Will Sawin: Right. I was implicitely assuming that all branch points of the coverings are rational over $K$.